# what does end point mean in terms of Ceilometer API python?

Tags: python, openstack, keystone, ceilometer

I am new to openstack, trying to use Ceilometer python API to pull some data from a testbed server but I get this error I do not understand, what does it need as an endpoint?

```
raise exceptions.EndpointNotFound()
keystoneclient.openstack.common.apiclient.exceptions.EndpointNotFound
```

My code is very simple,

```
import ceilometerclient
import ceilometerclient.client
import ceilometerclient.v2 as c_client


OS_USERNAME="myusername"
OS_PASSWORD="mypassword"
OS_TENANT_NAME="myproject"
OS_AUTH_URL="url"

cclient = ceilometerclient.client.get_client(2, os_username=OS_USERNAME, os_password=OS_PASSWORD, os_tenant_name=OS_TENANT_NAME, os_auth_url=OS_AUTH_URL)

samples = cclient.meters.list()
for s in sample:
    print s;
    print;
```

Answer (score 0):

An "endpoint" simply means "the URL at which you contact a service".  In OpenStack, the `keystone` service maintains a "catalog" of API endpoints.  When you create a Ceilometer client object, it asks the service catalog for the URL of the `metering` service.

If this service were not listed in your Keystone catalog, you would see this error.

You can see the endpoints currently configured in your catalog by running `openstack endpoint list` (if you have the `openstack` unified client available):

```
$ openstack endpoint list
+------...+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| ID   ...| Region    | Service Name | Service Type  |
+------...+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| c700a...| RegionOne | myservice    | messagequeue  |
| 4bd81...| RegionOne | keystone     | identity      |
| a2e5f...| RegionOne | nova         | compute       |
| 30483...| RegionOne | heat         | orchestration |
| f4ab0...| RegionOne | neutron      | network       |
| 482d9...| RegionOne | cinder       | volume        |
| e2615...| RegionOne | myservice    | messagequeue  |
| e7ef8...| RegionOne | ceilometer   | metering      |
| 41a1d...| RegionOne | nova_ec2     | ec2           |
| 9a7b8...| RegionOne | glance       | image         |
| 5bb58...| RegionOne | cinder_v2    | volumev2      |
+------...+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

If you don't have the unified client available, you can use a
combination of `keystone service-list` and `keystone endpoint-list` to
get the same information.

If your environment doesn't list the `metering` service, you probably
need to follow [these instructions](http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/yum/content/ceilometer-install.html) (look for the step labelled " the Telemetry Service with the Identity Service so that other OpenStack services can locate it").

Comment: okay, I understand the url part but how can I add an endpoint to my code,OS_ENDPOIN="url" does not work,